# declaring a sheet for the entire calculation - vba

Tags: vba, declaration, worksheet

I am using a user interface sheet for my command button and a calculation sheet to do the calculation in using the following code:

```
Worksheets("calculation").Cells(i, "E").Value
```

I used this "Worksheets("calculation"). " before every single "cell.value" to make sure that the outputs are printed in the right sheet.

Is there any code that I can use in the very beginning to let the model know which sheet I am working on? I do not want to use 
"Worksheets("calculation")."
over and over again?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a reference to `Worksheets("Calculation")` like this:

```
Set ws = Worksheets("Calculation")
```

This means you can use `ws.Cells(i, "E").Value` and use the `ws` anywhere you had the `Worksheets("Calculation")` statement.

If you don't really want to refer to all of the individual cell statements with `ws` then you could use a `with` statement to minimise your effort:

```
Function Something()
Dim ws as WorkSheet : Set ws = Worksheets("Calculation")
With ws
' do all the things you like
.Cells(1, "E").value = whateverYouLike 
.Cells(3, "A").value = somethingElse
End With
End Function
```

inside the `With`, you don't need to refer to the worksheet, just the methods and objects in question.

Comment: It is just making the "Worksheets("Calculation")" shorter. Still the problem is remained unsolved.

Comment: Edited answer with more info; does that meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Dave is correct, but is better to use the logic name and not the User name for reference to the worksheet.
I put in the commentary the alternative.

[image: VBACode]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'set ws = SheetCalculation
    SheetCalculation.Select
    'ws.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I can not read your code. Could you please edit and put it one more time. Tnx